# Missing commas from a string

Tags: c#, sql, string, string-concatenation

I'm trying to write a custom query generator for a small database that I'm making, but the comma that should appear in between all the entries to the string aren't appearing only the one at the end is.

```
private void BTN_advancedSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Creates the variable part of the custom query
        string customwhereclause = "";

        if (CHK_enableGameName.Checked == true)
        {
            Connectqry(customwhereclause);
            customwhereclause += "Game.GameName LIKE '%" + TXT_addGame.Text + "%'";
        }

        if (CHK_enableGenreName.Checked == true)
        {
            Connectqry(customwhereclause);
            customwhereclause += "Genre.GenreID =" + genreID + "";
        }

        if (CHK_enableConsoleName.Checked == true)
        {
            Connectqry(customwhereclause);
            customwhereclause += "Console.ConsoleID =" + consoleID + "";
        }

        if (CHK_enablePlayers.Checked == true)
        {
            Connectqry(customwhereclause);
            customwhereclause += "Game.Players >=" + NUD_players.Value + "";
        }
        if (CHK_enableDisc.Checked == true)
        {
            if (CHK_discOwned.Checked == true)
            {
                Connectqry(customwhereclause);
                customwhereclause += "Game.Disc ='" + "yes" + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                Connectqry(customwhereclause);
                customwhereclause += "Game.Disc ='" + "no" + "'";
            }
         }
         if (CHK_enableCompleted.Checked == true)
         {
            if (CHK_completed.Checked == true)
            {
                Connectqry(customwhereclause);
                customwhereclause += "Game.Completed ='" + "yes" + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                Connectqry(customwhereclause);
                customwhereclause += "Game.Completed ='" + "no" + "'";
            }
        }

        //varible query code being passed back to search form.
         frm_search.Cstmqry = customwhereclause;

        //close the form and reopen the other one.
         this.Close();
         frm_search.Show();
    }

    private void Connectqry(string s)
    {
        if (s == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the query is blank");
        }
        else
        {
            s = s + " , ";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

the output is currently this:

```
the query is blank

Game.GameName LIKE '%name%' ,

Game.GameName LIKE '%name%'Genre.GenreID =0 ,

Game.GameName LIKE '%name%'Genre.GenreID =0Console.ConsoleID =0 , 

Game.GameName LIKE '%name%'Genre.GenreID =0Console.ConsoleID =0Game.Players >=1 ,

Game.GameName LIKE '%name%'Genre.GenreID =0Console.ConsoleID =0Game.Players >=1Game.Disc ='no' ,
```

I'm not sure why it's removing the commas that be in between the string.

Comment: You are also forgetting the `AND` or `OR` operator...

Comment: You should return the new string (s) from Connectqry and add this to customwhereclause before the rest of the statement.

Comment: It's not removing the commas. They're there at the end, exactly as you wrote: `s = s + " , "` If you want commas between the predicates, well then, you'd better code that in, because `BTN_advancedSearch_Click` does not add commas at all.

Comment: ok , I didnt mean to over look that. considered it closed.

Comment: You might also want to consider using `string.Join` instead.  Or at least consider using a `StringBuilder` versus string concatenation.

Comment: This post may help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792603/how-are-strings-passed-in-net

Comment: Code for me is poor readable. 1 ` if (CHK_enableCompleted.Checked == true)` is reedundant, give ` if (CHK_enableCompleted.Checked )` 2. method `Connectqry` name is misleading

Comment: **Warning: your code is open to *SQL Injection Attacks***.  Rather than embedding parameter values in query strings, you should **always** construct parameterized queries.  See: [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5468425/3744182) and [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customwhereclause))
{
    customwhereclause += " AND ";
}
customwhereclause += // Your condition
```

in all your conditions. It'll add an `AND` operator everywhere it's necessary.

---

Even better:

```
private static string computeCondition(string current, string newCondition)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(current))
    {
        current += " AND ";
    }
    return current + newCondition;
}

private void BTN_advancedSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Creates the variable part of the custom query
    string customwhereclause = "";

    if (CHK_enableGameName.Checked == true)
    {
        Connectqry(customwhereclause);

        customwhereclause = computeCondition(customwhereclause, "Game.GameName LIKE '%" + TXT_addGame.Text + "%'");
    }
    ...
```

To avoid too big code dup

---

Or even better:

```
private void BTN_advancedSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Creates the variable part of the custom query
    List<string> whereClausesList = new List<string>();

    if (CHK_enableGameName.Checked == true)
    {
        Connectqry(customwhereclause);

        whereClausesList.Add("Game.GameName LIKE '%" + TXT_addGame.Text + "%'");
    }
    ...
    string.Join(" AND ", whereClausesList);
```

as suggested by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563532/rob)

Comment: Just add ! before string.IsNullOrEmpty to negate this statement.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customwhereclause))` since you want to add it if you already have a condition in there...

Comment: Didn't the OP want commas, not AND?

Comment: A tidier way (and most likely more performant) would be to store the clauses in a list, and at the end return `string.Join(" AND ", clauses);` - rather than checking if the expression is empty or not each time

Comment: @juharr that's true, but I doubt that sql condition can be concatenated with comas

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because `string` is immuteable.  When you do string concatenation like `s = s + " , ";` this is not updating the object that `s` references.  It's creating a new `string` and assigning the reference to `s`.  And because you don't pass `s` as a `ref` you are only updating a local copy of the reference and not the original.  The correct way to fix that is to return the new `string` and assign it.

```
private string Connectqry(string s)
{
    if (s == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the query is blank");
    }
    else
    {
        s = s + " , ";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    return s;
}
```

and use it like

```
customwhereclause = Connectqry(customwhereclause);
```

As other's have mentioned you probably want to use "AND" instead of commas, and using `string.Join` or `StringBuilder` would likely be more efficient, but `string` being immutable and string concatenation creating a new string is why your current code doesn't do what you expect.