# finding Index of particular Action In Queue

Tags: c#, indexing, queue

So i am making A Queue of Actions, which get invoke at whatever time, what i need is to get each session Queue Position.
I've tried doing A Queue of Action, passing the Session name, and than looking up the index, but it always returns -1.

```
public static Queue<Action<string>> myQ = new Queue<Action<string>>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myQ.Enqueue((string i) =>
    {
        i = "First";
    });
    myQ.Enqueue((string i) =>
    {
        i = "Second";
    });
    myQ.Enqueue((string i) =>
    {
        i = "Third";
    });
    int index = myQ.ToList().IndexOf((string i) =>
    {
        i = "First";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(index);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: If you need to find actions at certain positions why are you using a queue?

Comment: That's the most suited method for my needs, as action pile up in the Queue they are not instantly invoked, only at certain times when conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>.IndexOf` method searches for specified object in the list. For reference types (and `Action<string>` is a reference type) the items are compared by reference equality, i.e. object variables should actually reference the same object.

In your case a new `Action<string>` object is created each time when you specify

```
(string i) =>
{
    i = "First";
}
```

That's the reason why `IndexOf()` call returns `-1`.

Easiest fix is to pass the same object to `IndexOf()` call:

```
var firstAction = (string i) =>
        {
            i = "First";
        };
myQ.Enqueue(firstAction);

// ...

int index = myQ.ToList().IndexOf(firstAction);
```

The more flexible approach is to define a simple class that has Session name as a property on which you can search:

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public string SessionName { get; }

    public Action<string> Action => i => i = SessionName;

    public QueueItem(string sessionName)
    {
        SessionName = sessionName;
    }
}

Queue<QueueItem> myQ = new Queue<QueueItem>();
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("First"));
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("Second"));
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("Thrid"));
int index = myQ.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.SessionName == "First");
```

Another issue in your code is how you use `Action` to assign string variable. Consider this code:

```
string str = "One";
Action<string> action = x => x = "Two";
action(str);
```

After execution of this code, value of `str` would be `"One"`, not `"Two"`. When action is called, `str` is passed by value so any assignments to the parameter inside an action (or any other method) will not affect its initial value. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792603/how-are-strings-passed-in-net) for more details.

You could fix that by having `Func<string>` instead of `Action<string>` and using returned value in assignment:

```
public class QueueItem
{
    public string SessionName { get; }

    public Func<string> Func => () => SessionName;

    public QueueItem(string sessionName)
    {
        SessionName = sessionName;
    }
}

Queue<QueueItem> myQ = new Queue<QueueItem>();
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("First"));
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("Second"));
myQ.Enqueue(new QueueItem("Thrid"));
var queueList = myQ.ToList();
int index = queueList.FindIndex(x => x.SessionName == "First");
var result = queueList[index].Func();
```