# Accessing a parent instance's properties?

Tags: c#, class, instance, system.reflection

Lets say I have a few classes that looks a bit like these:

This class I'll call the **parent instance**:

```
public class Foo : Disposable {
    public Foo() {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
        FullPath = string.empty;
    }
    public Foo(string szInfo) {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
        ImportantInfo = szInfo;
    }
    ~Foo() => this.Dispose(false);
    /* IDisposible stuff cropped for simplicity */

    public string ImportantInfo {get; internal set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars {get; internal set;}

    public void SomeContainerLoadMethod() {
        /* Add some bars here */
        Bars.Add( new Bar() );
        Bars.Add( new Bar() );
        /* etc... */
    }
}
```

As you can see here, the parent instance `Foo` holds onto some `Bar` classes.
I'll call these `Bar` classes in the `List<Bar>` the **child instance containers** in this question.  Here's the definition of the `Bar` class in the example code way:

```
public class Bar : Disposable {
    Bar() { }
    ~Bar() => this.Dispose(false);
    /* IDisposable stuff cropped for simplicity */

    public string CoolBuff {get; internal set;}

    public void SomeCoolStringBufMethod() {
        /* Do something to populate CoolBuff, but I need ImportantInfo! */
    }
}
```

How would I access `ImportantInfo` from the parent instance , in the **child instance container**'s  `SomeCoolStringBufMethod()` ?

Here are the complications to this problem:

1. Doing it **without** having to make a duplicate `ImportantInfo` property and pass it into the child instance container's constructor
2. Doing it **without** having to pass `ImportantInfo` in as an argument when the child instance's `SomeCoolStringBufMethod()` method is called from
   the parent .

Is this possible, say with `System.Reflection`, to 'look up' the fact a `Bar` is a member of a `Foo`, and fetch `Foo`'s `ImportantInfo` property ?

Comment: `Bar` contains no reference to `ImportantInfo` and also no reference to `Foo`. Therefore, this is impossible. In order for `Bar` to get at `ImportantInfo`, you must give it something that it can trace back to it, whether the `ImportantInfo` itself or an instance of an object that references it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The two options you list are really the only way to do it.

Remember that any class instance exists at an address in memory. Variables just tell your application where to look in memory for the data. So sure, you can use reflection to find the `ImportantInfo` property of an instance of `Foo`, but which instance? Where should it look for it in memory? You have to know where in memory to look.

You know where in memory to look by using a variable. So you need to pass a variable to `Bar` somehow.

If there was a way to use reflection to find every active instance of a class, you could use that to figure it out in a round-about way, but there is no way to do that.

A small note: when you pass a `string` to a method, you aren't creating a duplicate. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10792823/1202807) if you're interested.

Comment: LeY provided a bit more info about GC tracing in regards to memory but you where the first to answer.  You're both right in this case.  It doesn't seem practical nor savvy at runtime to try and search through memory to find the ``Foo``class attached to the ``Bar``.  I'll sadly have to stick to passing in either an argument to ``Bar``'s method or sharing ``ImportantInfo`` with Bar via its constructor.  Though I feel like shared items for instantiated elements within a class's scope should be a thing guess that's not how this works, sadly.

Comment: You also mentioned passing them by reference instead to save the memory.  In this case my logic in thinking was to save memory say, if I needed to share a large buffer or something with a class.  Passing by reference remedies that worry in the way I was thinking about things.

Comment: Right. Just make sure you understand how passing by reference works since you can pass a reference by value, or pass a reference by reference (using `ref`), and the effects can be different if you're not careful. That article I linked to explains it.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer is NO.

Long Answer is Theoretically Yes, but Practically No.

Because you `Bar` have no reference to `Foo` at all, so you can't even tell which `Foo` contain your `Bar`, you can't even tell if your `Bar` is referenced by any `Foo` at all.

In order to figure that all , you have to trace back who is referencing your `Bar`.

In Theory it could be done using technique like GC,but GC does reference search from Top to Bottom which means from GC root to `Foo` then to your `Bar` , is doesn't do Bottom to Top. You can build your external double linked GC like `Foo`,`Bar` Graphic.

In Practice this will take you huge amount of effort, after that, you are also facing the Challenge to manage your own GC cycle of your ``` Foo``Bar ``` graphic.

So Short Answer is NO.

Comment: Think it would ever be practical to include objects a child class like this would inherit and be able to use ?  I'm speaking from MS's point of view on all that.  Of course what I'm asking probably isn't the smartest way of doing such things either.

Answer (score 1):

Number two is the way to go. (And no, I'm not trying to be funny.)

> ...pass `ImportantInfo` in as an argument when the child instance's `SomeCoolStringBufMethod()` method is called from the parent.

Methods are how classes interact with each other. Having a reference to another object is merely a means to the end of being able to call its methods and access its properties.

There's good reasons why we don't usually create classes with circular references between them. Imagine, for example, `Text.StringBuilder`. What if it had a reference to the class that created it, regardless of how it obtained that reference - via the constructor, reflection, or anything else.

What would `StringBuilder` do with that reference? In order to do anything with that object other than call `ToString()` it would need to know the type of that object. But if it knows the type of that object then it implies that `StringBuilder` only works if it has a reference to that type of object. That means the class that depends on `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder` can only be used in conjunction with each other.

Relating that back to your class: What does your child class need? Does `Bar` need a `Foo`? No. It needs a `string`. Any class that calls its method can give it a `string`. So why couple it to another class? One day you or someone else will need to make `Bar` work without a `Foo` and then you'll have a knot to untie.

If `Bar` depends on a `Foo` to get its `ImportantProperty`, that also makes unit testing very difficult. You'd have to create a `Foo` and then create a `Bar` so that the `Bar` can get its `ImportantProperty` from the `Foo`. If it depends on a `string` then it's easy to test. The test only has to create a `string`.

In your example, passing `ImportantProperty` to a `Bar` constructor wouldn't make sense because it's a writable property of `Foo`. That means `Foo` can change it, and then all the `Bar`s will have a different property unless you create all new ones. (Perhaps the fact that `ImportantProperty` can change is the reason why you want a reference back to the parent, but passing a `string` to a method call still solves that problem.)

You can almost certainly make this work without the child containing its own reference to the parent. If it must have that reference then it would make sense to pass that reference to the constructor of the child.