# C# Weak-referenced object alive after `using` block

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Based [on this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578967/how-can-i-write-a-unit-test-to-determine-whether-an-object-can-be-garbage-collec), I wanted to see if not disposing an `HttpClient` object creates leaks (which does, but nothing new here). However, what I've also found is that if I don't dispose a `HttpClient` object, the returned `HttpResponseMessage` is not garbage collected.

Here's the test. I've provided a [reproducing fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xo6iKu).

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace HttpClientTest
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static T CallInItsOwnScope<T>(Func<T> getter)
        {
            return getter();
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var wRef2 = CallInItsOwnScope(() =>
            {
                using (var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")).Result)
                {
                    return new WeakReference(response);
                }
            });
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine($"Alive: {wRef2.IsAlive}");

            client.Dispose();

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine($"Alive: {wRef2.IsAlive}");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling under .NET Framework 4.7.2, The output is as follows:

```
Alive: True
Alive: False
```

*Edit:* using .NET Core, I get the expected result:

```
Alive: False
Alive: False
```

My question is, why `HttpResponseMessage` is still alive after I disposed it, but only if I don't dispose it's creator?

(Looking at `HttpClient`'s sources I found that there is indeed a reference to the `HttpResponseMessage` being held, but this is deep into async land for me to really understand what's going on (`SetTaskCompleted` -> `TaskCompletionSource<>.TrySetResult()`))

Comment: Why do you want to `Dispose` your `HttpClient`. The general recommendation is to let them live forever.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why an `HttpResponse` object would leak. I'm not worried about `HttpClient`, in fact, I fear disposing it too often could lead to socket exhaustion.

Comment: I'm getting `False`, `False`, so there's some details missing here if you want others to see what you're seeing.

Comment: I have a plain .net framework 4.7.2 console application, and it returns the results above. Using a .net core console application returns false for both cases.

Comment: You should wait at least a bit before jumping on closing a question, Damien. Here's a Fiddle for you to see. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xo6iKu

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need look at this [MSDN - HttpClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1).

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.

Anyway, here is what you missed.

```cs
public void CallServiceTest()
{
    var wRef2 = CallInItsOwnScope(() =>
    {
        // HttpClient -> HttpMessageInvoker(IDisposable), so it can be disposed.
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        { 
            using (var response = client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")).Result)
            {
                return new WeakReference(response);
            }
        }
    });
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Assert.IsFalse(wRef2.IsAlive);
}
```

Comment: I've reformulated this question. My actual problem is `HttpResponseMessage` leaking when not disposing its creator.